# Azure Application Insights agent for Java causing Could not find or load main class %JAVA_OPTS on JBoss 18

Tags: azure, wildfly, azure-application-insights, javaagents

I am implementing Azure Application Insights in Java application.  [Azure Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-get-started?tabs=maven)

I have added below configure in standalone.conf [JBOSS/WildFly configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-arguments#standalone-server)

However when I start the server I am getting below error

```
[root@server-1 bin]# ./standalone.sh
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /opt/wildfly

  JAVA: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_261/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server %JAVA_OPTS% -javaagent:/tmp/azurejar/applicationinsights-agent-2.6.1.jar

=========================================================================

Error: Could not find or load main class %JAVA_OPTS
```

Could you please help me to resolve this issue ? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You're somehow mixing Windows and Linux here.  While you show running `standalone.sh` it looks like this is really `standalone.bat` as this is Windows syntax to access an environment variable.  Did you rename something?

Comment: @stdunbar - No I have added JAVA_OPTS="%JAVA_OPTS% -javaagent:/tmp/lib/applicationinsights-agent-2.6.1.jar" in standalone.conf file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's Windows syntax. In a Unix-based environment like Linux you use the `$` to access environment variables. Change the `%JAVA_OPTS%` part of the line to `$JAVA_OPTS`, i.e.:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -javaagent:/tmp/lib/applicationinsights-agent-2.6.1.jar"
```